# ParseUser Unity SDK missing definition for Password

Tags: c#, sdk, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am trying to signup a new [ParseUser](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html) using the Unity SDK (Parse 1.3.2). I follow the tutorial and use the code below to do the signup, however, I get an error:

**'Parse.ParseUser' does not contain a definiton for 'Password'**

Why does it recognize Username and Email, but not Password? It is driving me nuts...

My code:

```
var user = new ParseUser()
 {    
         Password= myPassword,
         Username = name,
         Email = "email@example.com"
 };        

 user.SignUpAsync();
```

Comment: is it possible that the omitted space after Password and before = is causing this issue?

Comment: Oh, I didnt see that, but that is not the problem cause. It still does not work even with a blank space after Password.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will do:

```
var user = new ParseUser();
user.setEmail(Email);
user.setUserName(..);
user.setPassword(..);
```

Comment: Thank you David, but apparently Parse.ParseUser has no definition for "setEmail", "setUserName" or "setPassword"...

Comment: @user2109099, please refer to https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html

Comment: Thats the Android documenatation, I am using the Unity API (dotnet: http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/Index.html). It should have a definition for the Password property, but I still cannot use it.

Comment: if you have android api, you can create a folder plugins\Android, and then write a java class (*.jar) that exposes such api, it is very easy! Just put the jar file in that folder, that is it!

Comment: I didnt get to try that, because my code suddenly started working and a Parse user now gets successfully created. The Password property is still highlighted as an error in Monodevelop though, which is weird...