# ParseUser Missing Definition for password

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Creating new User was working just fine until the password (text) turn maroon and now it says <'Parse.ParseUser does not contain a definition for 'Password'

Here's my code:

```
    var user = new ParseUser ()
    {
        Username    = n[0],
        Password    = n[1],
        Email       = n[2]

    };
```

What's missing?

This question has been asked before,
[ParseUser Unity SDK missing definition for Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697651/parseuser-unity-sdk-missing-definition-for-password/30549229#30549229)
Apparently, there was no answer to I had to create another question.

Comment: It was working just fine a while ago. Now it has stuck so bad I can't seem to shake it off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was foolish enough to believe MonoDevelop. When I finally wised up and clicked build in Unity (even though MonoDevelop still claimed there was no definition for Password) there was no problem compiling.

However, the user doesn't seem to be created when I use SignUpAsync, but that might be something unrelated.